# Firebase/AngularJS Bootstrap App does not adjust to mobile screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, firebase

I am new to firebase and Angular. I just tried to build an app and it seems like there is something not working with the bootstrap grid.
When i make the window smaller, the app adjusts.
But when i try it with the Console & the Mobile Sizes, the App does not adjust to the screensize as a normal bootstrap website does. 
You can see for yourself:

Maybe I just aligned the scripts false...
I also tried to switch from jquery to UI Bootstrap, but it is also not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nipfct">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">


    <title>Nobody is perfect</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="theme/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/js/scripts.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
```

Scripts.js

```
    var nipfctView = angular.module('nipfct', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'ui.bootstrap']);


      nipfctView.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider


            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            .when('/settings', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/settings.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });

    nipfctView.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this meta tag in your head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```